# Utilize GPU in Dart / Flutter other than graphics

Tags: multithreading, dart, flutter, gpu

Aye Aye good people,

I was wandering if I can 'use' ('calls', 'threads'?)

the GPU with Dart and Flutter.

The [documentation](https://flutter.github.io/devtools/timeline.html#gpu) states

> The GPU thread executes graphics code from the Flutter Engine. This
>   thread takes the layer tree and displays it by talking to the GPU
>   (graphic processing unit). You cannot directly access the GPU thread
>   or its data, but if this thread is slow, it’s a result of something
>   you’ve done in the Dart code. Skia, the graphics library, runs on this
>   thread, which is sometimes called the rasterizer thread.[...] More
>   information on profiling the GPU thread can be found at flutter.dev.
>   (which doesn't add much)

But what if I don't want to use it for graphics?

Let's say for example that I want to use [Monte carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), 
for some calculation,

could I make a call or send a thread to the GPU?

thank you for your attention

Comment: why not using [compute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function?

Comment: pskink I didn't know it existed and looks awesome, I'm gonna look into it right now! many thanks <3
bonus question: this is flutter stuff, I'm also using aqueduct... any 'pure dart' equivalent?

Comment: see https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-async-beginner-friendly-guide-for-heavy-lifting-operations-cf8ec81833d7 or https://hackernoon.com/are-futures-in-dart-threads-2cdc5bd8063a

Comment: as I understand he's looking for something like [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"GPU thread" was a confusing name, so we renamed it to "raster thread". This thread is actually running on a CPU core, and its function is to rasterize graphics to be sent *to* the GPU. Many people assumed the thread is running on the GPU itself, but that is not the case. Thus, the rename.

(We renamed it pretty recently. Your original question used the correct terminology at the time.)

You cannot compile Dart code to be run on the GPU (like CUDA), unfortunately, the way you can do that [with C++](https://linuxhint.com/gpu-programming-cpp/), for example.

An option is to write your Monte Carlo routine in something like C++, then use Dart's [FFI](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) to call that routine from Dart code. This will run synchronously and as fast as you can make the C++ code go.

Comment: "its function is to rasterize graphics to be sent to the GPU". Flutter isn't doing any software rasterization on the CPU though right? Surely all the rasterization is done by the GPU. Do you mean it is traversing the scene graph / preparing command buffers to be sent to the GPU? This is the usual function of a CPU rendering thread.